# Wait until a specific Process has finished

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a C# .NET Application. The program is opens .bat file and should wait until it's done and continue. The problem is that the .bat file is opening another file (PowerShell script). The PowerShell Script must be run from inside the .bat file. The C# program continues shortly after the .bat was executed, because it opens the PowerShell file and closes.

Is it possible to let my C# program wait for the PowerShell process to exit even when I never started the PowerShell file from inside the C# program?

Code:

```
.cs

https://pastebin.com/fL0BDc0Q

.bat

https://pastebin.com/S8EvWHhn

.ps1

https://pastebin.com/Jbbr5K0F
```

Comment: Is it possible to let the C# Program watch a Process and continues when it ends like you can watch yourself in Taskmanager ?

Comment: Post the contents of the bat file, the ps file and the cs file

Comment: I Edited the Question so you have all the Code you need :)

Comment: It says expired, not available or removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("PowershellGUI.exe").FirstOrDefault()?.WaitForExit();
```

You may have to tweak if the process takes a while to appear. Probably need to wait until it's running, then run the above to wait for it to disappear again.